# newcommand for a code with \begin{...}

Tags: macros

I am trying to edit a text right now in a LaTeX file. In order to emphasize portions that are edited vs original, I wanted to add a new command to shorten it.

How would this syntax work here?

```
\newcommand{\revise}{\textcolor{red}{}} ...
```

I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: If you really want `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`, you should investigate `\newenvironment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Define your new command
\newcommand{\revise}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}} 

\begin{document}
This is an \revise{example}.
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can define a new command in latex by following syntax:

```
\newcommand{\name}[num]{definition}
```

where the name of the command you want to create (preceded by a backslash), and the definition of the command. The num argument in square brackets is optional and specifies the number of arguments the new command takes (up to 9 are possible).
Please read [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) for more information.

Comment: In this specific instance, you can also use `\newcommand{\revise}{\textcolor{red}}`.